# -bash: amplify: command not found (even after installing amplify) in MacBook

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

In my swift application we are aws amplify so I need install in my system.

After installing node modules,I installed typescript after that I installed amplify using following command (**sudo npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli --unsafe-perm=true**) and its was success but when give amplify -v it throws command not found error.

Note - In bin folder I can see npm,tsc but I cant see amplify.

If I run the application I am getting the following error.

```
warning: AmplifyTools has been deprecated. More info: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios/blob/main/AmplifyTools/README.md
(not in PATH env variable)
npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: amplify-app
error: Minimum version required of Amplify CLI is not installed.
  Min required version: (4.22.0)
  Found Version: ([0m5.0.0[0m)

To install the latest version, please run the following command:
  npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli@latest
```

[image: TERMINAL LOG]

Comment: I know it's a bit late, but why do you use `sudo` with your `npm`? Also, what is the output of `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli@latest`?

Comment: @Raptor may I know why you are using `sudo` and `--unsafe-perm=true`? I tested on my Mac M1 Pro, and `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli` works just fine. Did you also try using this command `curl -sL https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-cli/install | bash && $SHELL` ?

Comment: I'm not using those. Read carefully, it's OP who used the flags.